# Sencha Extjs DateField allow javascript injection issue

Tags: javascript, extjs, code-injection

The user is allowed to inject javascript in Extjs DateField. If you try to enter tag with javascript for example enter the following

`<img src=x onerror=alert(1)>` in the docs of datefield on Extjs site https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Date.html It will show you alert popup here is a screen shot. It shouldn't run javascript as this considered as code injection.

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boM8s.png)

Did any one face this issue before?

I tried to debug the code where the popup coming from but I wasn't able to find the root caller.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: The injection is certainly reproducible by visiting the URL provided in the image. (Run the fiddle and paste in the image tag). I was able to trace click event handling to an event delegation handler in a script with "debug" in its file name but was unable to trace it further. I suggest you notify Sencha support of the vulnerability and see what they say.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to the tooltip handling.

Here particular the code gets executed because it gets injected into the invalidText property.

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Date.html#cfg-invalidText

This is the default value:

```
"{0} is not a valid date - it must be in the format {1}"
```

You can circumvent this issue by removing the replacers or change the text at all. Furthermore check the input before processing it. Libraries like DOMpurify can help here or built in ExtJS functionalities like maskRe, regex properties - depending on the individual component used.

---

I dont think its related to the datefield, because this can be reproduced with the same value if you configure a numberfield like that:

```
{
        xtype: 'numberfield',
        anchor: '100%',
        name: 'bottles',
        fieldLabel: 'Bottles of Beer',
        value: 99,
        maxValue: 99,
        minValue: 0,
        invalidText:"{0} invalid"
    }
```

Its more related to the validation and error handling, which by default will display a tooltip. This tooltip needs to be properly sanitized.

---

As far as i know, this issue is present for years.

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.tip.ToolTip.html

Another example

```
Ext.getBody().appendChild({
    id: 'clearButton',
    html: 'Clear Button',
    style: 'display:inline-block;background:#A2C841;padding:7px;cursor:pointer;'
});

var tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
    target: 'clearButton',
    html: '<img src=x onerror=alert(1)>'
});
```